# Avoid two column balancing

Tags: two-column

I've the following problem: I have some text and some figures in a two column environment. If the the text gets long and my figure floats to the next page my second column gets stretch as you can see in the image below. If I comment out the figure everything is fine.
[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \blindtext[1]
    \blindlist{enumerate}
    \section{Section}
    \blindtext[1]
    \blindlist{enumerate}
    \section{Section}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5cm,5cm)
        \psframe(0,0)(5cm,5cm)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to have the second column not stretched? I played around with `\nobalance` command already but without success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you declared your picture as a "float" (`\begin{figure}[t]`) it would automatically move to the top of the next page/column when there isn't any room for it on the current page/columm.  that is, if the document class you're using permits it.  take a look at this question for some information on floats: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: You can use `\raggedbottom`.  Or `\filbreak` before the picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `\raggedbottom` did what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\raggedbottom` or `\filbreak` before the picture.